# Why does Android Studio dsplay Hint of MutableState<Sections> as Sections?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I use Android Studio Hint to display the type of a variable.

In Code A, the Hint of a is displayed as `MutableState<Sections>`, you can see Image A.

And the Hint of `currentSection` is displayed as `Sections`, you can see Image B, I think it should be `MutableState<Sections>`, right?

**Code A**

```
   val a = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(tabContent.first().section)}

   val (currentSection, updateSection) = rememberSaveable {       
        mutableStateOf(tabContent.first().section)
    }
```

**Image A**
[image]

**Image B**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a` and `currentSection` was expected to have different data type.

`currentSection` is assigned by using *destructuring declaration*

```
val (currentSection, updateSection) = rememberSaveable {
    ...
}
```

In jetpack compose, you can create state in multiple ways

- val mutableState = remember { mutableStateOf(default) }
- var value by remember { mutableStateOf(default) }
- val (value, setValue) = remember { mutableStateOf(default) }

You can also check in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-in-composables)

Comment: Thanks! I think both `a` and `currentSection`  are all the state, why are the Hint of Android  Studio differents?

Comment: The hint is showing the data type of `a` and `currentSection`, and both of them have different data type